# Trigger to do a count of assets based on brand and show on accounts

Tags: apex, trigger

We have multiple brands in Salesforce that we loaded in assets.

i am trying to do a roll-up summary on assets to determine how many assets account have by brand.

this is not possible through roll-up summary field out of the box.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you were to edit your post to include any code you've created to this point, I think you'd find others would be in a much better position to help you. You might also want to search existing posts related to triggers and best practices for guidance on getting started if you've not already done so.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just getting started writing the code to accomplish this, you might check out this library from Salesforce superstar Abhinav Gupta, which provides apex trigger and batch functionality for rolling up data from a child object in a lookup relationship.

https://github.com/abhinavguptas/Salesforce-Lookup-Rollup-Summaries

Abhinav takes care of the heavy lifting with this library but under the hood, he taking advantage of aggregate queries. If you set out writing this on your own, you'll want to understand how to write triggers and how aggregate queries work in this scenario:

http://macscloud.com/salesforce-apex-triggers-the-definitive-guide/
http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2010/02/10/using-aggregate-functions/

Once you've mastered triggers and aggregate queries, you should move on to understanding batch apex. There are certain scenarios in which your trigger will not fire (e.g. merge of parent records) and by having a batch process run cleanup, you're rollup field data is accurate.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

As Abhinav has architected it, the most efficient use of code is for your trigger and your batch to reuse as much of the same code as possible. If you do decide to write a trigger, batch process, and helper methods on your own, you should create a helper class and methods that both the trigger and the batch execute method use.

Hope this helps.